# Cloth simulation not working because of a missing step

Tags: animation, physics

I am trying to simulate some clothes in 2.8, I fixed a suit in marvelous designer on my character in T-pose, then did a retopology for the suit.

In Blender I:

- imported the character with an armature and the suit
- transferred weight from the body to the suit
- parented suit to the armature with empty groups
- added collision to the body and cloth physics to the suit and tried with this pinning group

[image]

- but I got a destructive result

[image]

- I tried different pinning group

[image]

- to get this result but not good for an animation

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please use the edit button on the bottom of your post and please don't connect your question only to a downloaded link, add reference images and a more understandable explanation of the problem, that way it will be easier to solve your problem. thank you.